# How to unit test methods which depend on a private field?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf, xunit

I just started writing some tests for a new project and encountered the following "problem":

I mocked the dependent `INotifyVariableChangedService` and `OpcClient` to test my `OpcService`:

```
private readonly OpcUaClient _client;
        private readonly INotifyVariableChangedService _notifyVariableChangedService;
        private readonly ushort _symbolicsIndex;

        public OpcService(INotifyVariableChangedService notifyVariableChangedService)
        {
            this._notifyVariableChangedService = notifyVariableChangedService;

            this._client = new OpcUaClient("", "");

            _symbolicsIndex = _client.GetSymbolicsNameSpaceId();
        }
```

Here you can see, that i get the `_symbolicsIndex`, which i only have to do one time. Consequently i'm persisting it in a field and reusing it whenever i need it again.

This brought up a problem when testing a method like this one, because it depends on the value in this field:

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetVariableValue(string nodeIdentifier, string variableName)
        {
            var variableValue = await this._client.GetValue(nodeIdentifier, variableName, _symbolicsIndex);

            return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(variableName, variableValue.Value);
        }
```

Of course i could refactor this and get the `_symbolicsIndex` everytime in my controller, but that does not seem like a clean solution at all.

Is there a way to "mock" this field ? Should i even be doing that at all or should i refactor it and expose a method, which sets the `_symbolicsIndex` in my service explicitly, instead of setting it in the constructor ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can mock a private field without using reflection, but I would suggest that you also have the client injected rather than instantiating it in the constructor.

You said the client is already a mocked object, so you could fake the `GetSymbolicsNameSpaceId()` method and return the desired mocked value, which is then set to the private field when the client is passed to the constructor.

This could then look something like this (assumed FakeItEasy as the mocking libary)

```cs
private readonly OpcUaClient _client;
private readonly INotifyVariableChangedService _notifyVariableChangedService;
private readonly ushort _symbolicsIndex;

public OpcService(INotifyVariableChangedService notifyVariableChangedService, OpcUaClient client)
{
    this._notifyVariableChangedService = notifyVariableChangedService;
    this._client = client;

    _symbolicsIndex = _client.GetSymbolicsNameSpaceId();
}
```

Test:

```cs
_notifyVariableChangedService = A.Fake<INotifyVariableChangedService>();
_client = A.Fake<OpcUaClient>();

A.CallTo(() => _client.GetSymbolicsNameSpaceId()).Returns(1);

_testee = new OpcService(_notifyVariableChangedService, _client);
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer.
Did exactly that and created an IOpcUaClient interface, to be able to mock the client successfully. Works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted with francWhite's answer.

If anyone reading this, wonders how it would look with Moq, here you go:

```
[Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var opcClientMock = new Mock<IOpcUaClient>();
        var notifyVariableChangedServiceMock = new Mock<INotifyVariableChangedService>();

        opcClientMock.Setup(x => x.GetSymbolicsNameSpaceId()).ReturnsAsync((ushort)7);            

        var opcService = new OpcService(notifyVariableChangedServiceMock.Object, opcClientMock.Object);
    }
```